# LNK1104 with NuGet Packages : DirectXTKAudioWin8.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, direct3d, directxtk

I have a Direct3D Application.

We use the NuGet Package `directxtk_desktop_2015`.
In recent packages like `directxtk_desktop_win10` or `directxtk_uwp`, I have additional `WICTextureLoader` flags which I want and need.
However, when I add these packages to NuGet, I receive the linker error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'DirectXTKAudioWin8.lib'

How can I resolve this?
This is my current packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="directxtk_desktop_win10" version="2020.8.15.1" targetFramework="native" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only *one* of those packages at a time. If you are currently using `directxtk_desktop_2015` and you are using VS 2019, then you should use `directxtk_desktop_2017` instead.

> I dropped VS 2015 support and deprecated `directxtk_desktop_2015` starting with the [February 2020 release](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/releases/tag/feb2020)

The `directxtk_desktop_2015` package only included the Windows 8+ version of *DirectX Tool Kit for Audio*, but with `directxtk_desktop_2017` I switched to using the [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/xaudio2redist) which supports Windows 7 SP1 or later. If you only require Windows 10 or later support, then use `directxtk_desktop_win10` instead. For UWP apps (i.e. not Win32 desktop apps), you'd use `directxtk_uwp`.

See the [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK#using-nuget-package-manager) for more details.

**UPDATE**: In this case, the problem was `.vcxproj` was not fully cleaned up to remove the references to `directxtk_desktop_2015`. Opening the `vcxproj` in a text editor and verifying which `targets` are being referenced found this issue.

Comment: As you can see, my packages.config only contains win10 package...

Comment: You must still have a reference to the ``directxtk_desktop_2015.targets`` targets in your projects because the other ``.targets`` do not reference ``DirectXTKAudioWin8.lib``. Open up your vcxproj files in a text editor and make sure you only have one NuGet for directxtk.

Comment: wow. Can you make this an answer? There was indeed a reference to an even more outdated target